# Cannot derive from sealed type 'StatefulService'

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I am trying to create a Service Fabric Application in Visual Studio 2017. steps are as follows.
[image]

Step2:Then from NewServiceFabricService I am selecting StatefulService under section .net Core 2.0
[image]

Then I am getting this error.
[image]

Any suggestion would be extremely helpful.

Comment: You're trying to derive the class from itself. Use a different name for your class or qualify the base class with a namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ouch!

Naming a class exactly the same as its base is your first error.

But a quick fix:

```
 class StatefulService : Full.Name.Space.StatefulService { ... }
```

A better fix, run the wizard again and pick a better name to get:

```
 class MyStatefulService : StatefulService { ... }
```